# Get index of selected row in filtered DataGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, indexing

I am using DataGrid class in WinForms and filter data using RowFilter.

```
//docRows = some DataTable
dgDocRow.DataSource = docRows;
docRows.DefaultView.RowFilter = "WHERE ID > 1"
```

Now grid displays only filtered rows

When I want to access selected row in the grid, I use

```
int i = docRows.CurrentRowIndex;
DataRow dr = ((DataTable)docRows.DataSource).Rows[i];
```

This, however, returns incorrect data, since `docRows.CurrentRowIndex` gives me index in filtered DataGrid and selection using `((DataTable)docRows.DataSource).Rows[i]` selects from original DataSource, which is not filtered.

How can I get the correct row/rowindex in new filtered DataSource? (without iterating through the whole table, which is how I do it now)

thanks, zbynek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get at the current row through the BindingContext and the Current property of the BindingManagerBase.

```
// dgDocRow is DataGrid
BindingManagerBase bm = this.dgDocRow.BindingContext[this.dgDocRow.DataSource, this.dgDocRow.DataMember];
DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)bm.Current).Row;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me -- dgDocRow has no property DataMember -- perhaps that is due to using .NET 3.5?
The application I am developing is for Windows CE, so I have to develop it in VS 2008, newer versions have no support for Compact Framework

Comment: Try pass string.Empty instead of DataMember.